# JS best practice for member functions

Tags: javascript, optimization, functional-programming

I'm writing a little mobile games library, and I'm not sure the best practice for declaring member functions of instantiated function objects.

For instance, I might create a simple object with one property, and a method to print it:

```
function Foo(id){
    this.id = id;
    this.print = function(){ 
        console.log(this.id); 
    };
};
```

However, a function which does not need access to 'private' members of the function does not need to be declared in the function at all. I could equally have written:

```
function print(){
    console.log(this.id);
};

function Foo(id){
    this.id = id;
    this.print = print;
};
```

When the function is invoked through an instance of Foo, the instance becomes the context for `this`, so the output is the same in either case.

I'm not entirely sure how memory is allocated with JS, and I can't find anything that I can understand about something this specific, but it seems to me that with the first example all members of Foo, including the print function, are duplicated each time it is instantiated - but with the second, it just gets a pointer to one, pre-declared function, which would save any more memory having to be allocated as more instances of Foo are created.

Am I correct, and if I am, is there any memory/performance benefit to doing this?

Comment: If you don't need access to private variables, the best practice is to add member functions to the prototype.

Comment: Hopefully the JS compiler can tell that the first function doesn't reference any closure variables, so it can reuse the same function for all instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, in the first case, every object created with the `Foo` constructor function will have an instance of the printer function. A simple way to avoid this is adding it to the `prototype` of `Foo`:

```
function Foo(id){
    this.id = id;
};

Foo.prototype.print = function () {
    console.log(this.id);
};
```

Or:

```
function Foo(id){
    this.id = id;
};

Foo.prototype = {
    print: function () {
        console.log(this.id);
    }
};
```

---

Suggested reading:

- [Mozilla Developer Network: Inheritance and the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)
- Douglas Crockford: JavaScript - The Good Parts

Comment: Cheers! However, I do have another question - what is the benefit, besides a kind-of namespace, to using a prototype over 'unbound' (I guess you could say - they're not global as they're inside an IIFE) functions? This way seems neater if you want otherwise unrelated objects to implement the same methods.

Comment: If you have two unrelated types, `function Foo(id) { this.id = id; }` and  `function Bar(id) { this.id = id; }`, and they are printed the same way, then you can add the same printing function to the prototype of both types: `Foo.prototype.print = Bar.prototype.print = function () { console.log(this.id); };`. The benefit of methods is they can access the properties of the instance they are called on via the `this` variable.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that making `print` a method is not strictly necessary (but convenient). If you have an "unbound" printing function which uses `this`, e.g. `function print2() { console.log(this.id); }`, then you can call it on both `Foo` and `Bar` objects w/o adding it to the prototypes: `var foo = new Foo(42); print2.call(foo);` and `var bar = new Bar(123); print2.call(bar);`. Details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: But 'unbound' (don't know the correct term, we'll go with this!) functions can access the instance they are called on with 'this' as well...apart from the semantics, there doesn't appear to be a difference in behaviour, so I figured it must be for the sake of clean code and/or performance.

Comment: "But 'unbound' (don't know the correct term, we'll go with this!) functions can access the instance they are called on with 'this' as well." - Yes, this is what `print2.call(foo);` does, it sets the `this` variable to `foo`. If you write this: `print2();` then `this` will refer to the global object. I almost forgot to mention the simplest technique: you can entirely avoid using the `this` variable if you pass the object as an argument: `function print3(obj) { console.log(obj.id); }`, and then: `print3(foo);` and `print3(bar);`

Comment: "...apart from the semantics, there doesn't appear to be a difference in behaviour, so I figured it must be for the sake of clean code and/or performance." - Yes, all these techniques give you the same output, that is, all of them will print the `id` of the object. If one has experience with classic OOP languages (C++, Java, C# etc.) than the first version which adds `print` to the prototype to define a method looks cleaner. Sure writing `foo.print();` is clean, but I think `print2.call(foo);` and `print3(foo);` look clean as well.